# XCode 4.2 static libraries linking issue

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, llvm

I have **Core** static library, a few **Component** static libraries that relays on the **Core** one, and then there is an **App** that links against both **Core** and **Component** libraries. My **App** can link both against **Core** and **Component** as long as **Component** don't uses classes from **Core** (**App** uses classes from **Core**).

I got the following error in both armv6 and armv7 versions. So my problem is not the very popular linking issue that everyone has.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added reference to **Core** in **Component** and even added it in "Link Binary With Libraries" which shouldn't be necessary for static lib.

*Since I start having this issue I start doubting my design... It probably makes more sense in dynamically linking environment but still it should be doable in static one, especially since this already works under Windows with MSVC compilers*.

**Edit:**
I made some progress! Although I still don't know where to go with it.

Here is my setup:

- **Core** has a class cResourceManager that has a templated method GetResource<T>(int id)
- **Core** also has class cResource
- **Component** has class cMesh that inherits cResource

Here are some tests:

- If I try from **App** to call rm->GetResource<cMesh>(...) I get the linking error
- If I try from **App** to construct cMesh I get linking the linking error
- If I try from **App** to call static method that will return new instance of cMesh I get the linking error
- **If I comment out the construction of cMesh but leave other member cMesh function calls the App links fine.** I can even call **delete mesh**.

*I have never seen anything like it!*

Comment: Hopefully this will help... (currently 100%)

Comment: The design is sound, we're using a similar approach for two iOS apps; so it's almost certainly "only" a configuration issue of some kind.

Comment: @rvalue Yes I'm also targeting iOS. Currently my only idea is that I'm probably making some circular dependency with a templates factory or something. I introduce new resource types with the modules but the Core has templates resource factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `cMesh` constructor, then you are then using the default (no argument, no body) `cMesh` constructor that is given to you.  It almost sounds like there's a build error or missing code as a result of some code in your `cMesh` constructor and so the library isn't actually getting generated, and perhaps Xcode isn't reporting the error.  Xcode is no good at reporting linker errors.

I would suggest looking at what symbols the linker says are missing and double-check that they are actually defined in your code.  My guess is that you're using one of those symbols in your `cMesh` constructor.  A lot of times with virtual base classes, you may forget to define *and* implement a method or two in a child class.  Could be a result of missing a method based on your template, or your template isn't `#include`d correctly.  This could compile fine but result in linker errors like you're seeing.

If Xcode isn't showing you the full linker error, show the Log Navigator (<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>), double-click the last "Build " entry, select the error, and then press the button on the far-right of the row that appears when selected.  The symbols should be listed there.  If not, it's time for `xcodebuild` in the Terminal.

If it's **not** that case, I'd be interested in seeing the results of whether or not the library is being built for the appropriate architecture, or maybe this can spur some progress:

1. In the Xcode Organizer <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, click Projects and find the path to the DerivedData for your project.
2. In the Terminal, navigate to that directory (`cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/proj-<random value>/`)
3. Remove (or move aside) the Build directory (`rm -r Build`)
4. In Xcode, try to build with the `cMesh` constructor present.
5. Find the Library product file (`cd Build/Products/<scheme>-iphoneos`)

Your compiled static libraries (`<libname>.a`) should be in this directory.  If they're not there, they didn't build (unless you put your products elsewhere).  If your libraries are there, let's confirm that they actually are getting built for the appropriate architecture.  Run `otool -vh <library>.a`.  You should see something like:

```
$ otool -vh libtesting.a 
Archive : libtesting.a
libtesting.a(testing.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC     ARM         V7  0x00      OBJECT     3       1928 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
```

As you can see, my test library was built for ARMv7.

Comment: The issue is really strange... XCode didn't report the symbol or at least it did look like it was the whole class missing. I start removing pieces until I manage to narrow down the problematic symbol. It is the destructor of cResource. There is nothing special about it, I manage to make it empty public virtual destructor. If I make the destructor inline I can link, if it's defined in the .cpp then it doesn't link. My constructor is also in the same .cpp file also few other function and they don't seem to be a problem.

Comment: My code base is massive build in over 3 years of work. cResource is used everywhere in it. And since I currently have active projects that don't use Components and they work just fine also my Component app compiles and links under MSVS... I think it may be some compiler/linker issue. I'll give it another try to figure out some more information about this.

Comment: The missing symbols will appear immediately before "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture."  If you're having the problem where the implementation in the .h works but symbol not found in the .cpp, are you *sure* the .cpp is getting build into the library?  Sounds like it's only getting build because it's being included in another translation unit.  This could be problem with a circular dependency in your libraries (sounds like you have several static libraries which uses other static libraries).

Comment: You can also use `nm` to check for undefined symbols in your library.  The second column is "U" when the symbol is undefined, so `nm <lib>.a | grep -E "^(\ *)U"`.  Look for symbols from your project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are linking them in the correct order.

If Component depends on symbols in Core, then Component needs to be first in the link order, so the linker knows which symbols to look for in Core.

In MSVC the order doesn't matter, but in most other compiler suites it does.

Comment: I had the order wrong but unfortunately the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Clang generates code for armv6, if you're targeting devices that old you still need to use GCC.

Comment: I don't think my problem is code generation. I have exactly the same error for armv7 as well. Plus I get the error even if I use LLVM GCC 4.2

Comment: Fair enough, we had a similar issue with our first efforts in migrating to Clang.  Can you link the Component targets against Core directly (as well)?